# What are the some of the best (dis)engagement mechanism for small gears?

Tags: gears, robotics

I’m planing to build a robot out of gears.  I was wondering what kind of (dis) engagement mechanism would be suitable for gears that are about 2.5cm (1 inch) in diameter.

PS: preferably, (dis)engagement of gears accomplished without stopping.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at any gearboxes? especially ones with hydraulic clutches?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I just looked up hydraulic clutches but they tend to be too big like 25cm in length.  I need smaller mechanism preferably.

Comment: I made the suggestion so you could see HOW they work, not that you just buy those bits - so you could design something for yourself...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I’ll learn how they work and possibly use them in the future!

Comment: Electromagnetic clutches perhaps might be more appropriate?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I didn’t know there was such a thing, I’ll look into them right now!